# Reshaping data in a postgres query?

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables in CartoDB, one of community district polygons, and one of sites that are in those community districts.

I know the district (borocd) of each site, so I can get a list of counts of sites of each type with:

```
SELECT borocd, type, count(*) FROM sites GROUP BY borocd, type
```

But I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how I'd update my "districts" table with columns for count of type1 and count of type2 in a single query. I wound up doing this:

```
UPDATE districts
SET type1_sites = (
  SELECT count(*) FROM sites
  WHERE type='type1' AND districts.borocd = sites.borocd
  GROUP BY borocd
  )
```

And repeating that for type 2. But could I have done that more cleanly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE districts
SET type1_sites = (
  SELECT count(*) FROM sites WHERE type='type1' AND districts.borocd = sites.borocd
), 
    type2_sites = (
  SELECT count(*) FROM sites WHERE type='type2' AND districts.borocd = sites.borocd
);
```

Assuming you have separate columns for type1 and type2.

Comment: Um, right. That is actually kind of obvious. I think I'm overtired.